# How to make cols="" work when a textarea is in a grid container

Tags: html, css, textarea, css-grid

Somehow both Chrome and Firefox don't seem to respect the `cols` attribute on `textarea` elements when these reside in a grid container:

```css
.grid { display: grid; }

textarea:not([cols]) { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<h2>Not in a grid container:</h2>

<div>
  <textarea cols="10" rows="6">some dummy text</textarea>
  <textarea>some other text</textarea>
</div>

<h2>In a grid container:</h2>

<div class="grid">
  <textarea cols="10" rows="6">some dummy text</textarea>
  <textarea>some other text</textarea>
</div>
```

The `rows` attribute is being respected as I'd expect.

I need a `texarea` that respects `cols` when *inside* a grid container, and if `cols` is not present, takes 100% of the available width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an alignment issue making the textarea stretched by default. You can fix this using margin `auto` on the right

```css
.grid { display: grid; }

textarea:not([cols]) { width: 100%; }

textarea {
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>Not in a grid container:</h2>

<div>
  <textarea cols="10" rows="6">some dummy text</textarea>
  <textarea>some other text</textarea>
</div>

<h2>In a grid container:</h2>

<div class="grid">
  <textarea cols="10" rows="6">some dummy text</textarea>
  <textarea>some other text</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to take one block element parent to fix it.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
}

textarea:not([cols]) {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Not in a grid container:</h2>

<div>
  <textarea cols="10" rows="6">some dummy text</textarea>
  <textarea>some other text</textarea>
</div>

<h2>In a grid container:</h2>

<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <textarea cols="10" rows="10">some dummy text</textarea>
  </div>
  <textarea>some other text</textarea>
</div>
```